# HTML5 video not playing in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, video, opera

Having some issues with [this website](http://www.theothereye.tv)...

All the browsers play HTML5 video but Opera. It played before, but I can't see anything that would affect it in the recent update I did...

Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me, what opera version are you using?

Comment: what browser version? I just tried with latest snapshot and it worked fine

Comment: worked fine and plays video? I'm using the latest - I just get a blank screen, but I know it's playing as the events are firing :/

Comment: What OS are you on?  If you're on Windows, check that the gstreamer dlls got installed with Opera, could be something wrong with your install.  On Linux, I think the system gstreamer is used so check for those.

Comment: Youtube videos suddenly stopped working on my ubuntu 20.04 version. And I had installed all codecs and what not, but it ended up being a problem with my Bluetooth driver. Most of the time I work listening to music though my external speaker and youtube vids suddenly stop playing, and disconnecting the Bluetooth and reconnecting it made the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I finally fixed it's some problem with libffmpeg.so that comes with Opera, so we can use the library file that comes with Chromium. (kinda like what the guy above posted, but mine did not appriciate the symlinks.

install chromium browser from software manager, then:

```
 sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so.old

sudo cp /usr/lib/chromium/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
```

restart Opera

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of Opera. Go to [this repo](https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases) and download the relevant ffmped binary then extract and cut to your `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/` and restart Opera.

And thats it, you will be able to play the video you want.

Comment: You're nearly 10 years too late for this - it's probably fixed now

Comment: I am just adding a note for someone else. It might be 10 years late but I was looking for a solution to the same problem when I bumped into this.

Comment: After 11 years this solution is still not late. My Opera (91.0.4516.16) in Ubuntu 22.04 installed via apt (and not snap) doesn't play all videos. Ishmael's fix is easy and without the necessarity to install chromium. Only downside: this is not update proof. Last update from Opera 90 to 91 overwrote the library. Maybe write protecting would solve that.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Ubuntu 20.04 the problem exists again. At least in the scenario when Opera is installed using `apt-get`.

In Ubuntu 20.04 + the packages `chromium` and `chromium-ffmpeg` are now only available (in a not recent enough version) as snap. You might install Opera also as a snap to overcome the problem, which was not a solution for me, because I found no way how to migrate to the snap version of Opera with keepign all my settings.

In case Opera is installed with `apt-get` the file `libffmpeg.so` in the Opera directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera` must be replaced with a link to `sudo ln -s /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/current/chromium-ffmpeg-104195/chromium-ffmpeg/libffmpeg.so libffmpeg.so` Maybe the linked version (104195) must be adjusted so that Opera runs fine on your system (otherwise pages with videos will crash).

Answer (score 0):

I could not play the videos at www.edge.org. I was getting a message to the effect: can't play video with current setup. I fixed this by installing chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra using apt-get/aptitude. I'm using Opera version 50.0.2762.58 on Ubuntu Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Solution ...

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
```

Comment: Not a good solution if you don't explain why it's the solution

Comment: long story short .. opera is built over chromium browser just like google chrome, so there is a compatibility issue in the "libffmpeg.so", so in case your installed chromioum is newer you will face this issue and the solution is either to wait for opera to update their app or just do it by your self

Comment: just updated my system and run into the same problem and solve it the exact same way .. i hope opera can resolve this issue but for now this is the solution

Comment: This worked for me, and the original request was for a solution, not an explanation.  Thank you, Saleh.

Answer (score 0):

There is an automated solution for x86_64 systems: https://github.com/Ld-Hagen/fix-opera-linux-ffmpeg-widevine

It will download and install latest available libffmpeg.so and optionally WidevineCDM.
Also it could be started automatically after each Opera update on some systems.